# How do I save a client generated image to use later

Tags: javascript, class, save, user-input

I am making a game similar to Super Mario Bros for a school project. I would like to be able to have the user customize their Mario, but the number of possibilities of Marios is too big to just have all the possibilities laid out on an image file and select one based on what they choose. How can I save the custom user-created Mario to later be used in code? Essentially save it. I am new to JavaScript, so it would help if you explained well. I don't know where to begin. I have thought about spending a long time editing an image file with all the possible Marios on it, and selecting one, like I said before, but I don't even know how I would select one based on their input. The Mario that I am making is a class called "Mario" I have all my code in "index.js" under the folder name "src". All I need is to have the user-created Mario ready to use. I already know how I will have the user select an option for each aspect.

**EDIT:**  If anyone has any ideas, I am still open, but don't worry about it. It is for a school project, and so it doesn't need to be *amazing*. I was told I don't even have to succeed.

Comment: Can you share some of your code? Also, are you trying to save the custom character so that a user can log out and come back, the next day for example, and have the created character available again?

Comment: No, to both questions. I don't have any code, I just need ideas. I am thinking about using svg's and editing the output, but at this point, it's for a school project, and so I am thinking about just making a custom little character for everyone to use.